# Bash Script: Append parent directories to filenames

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

How can I universally append the parent directories of a filename to the filename itself, e.g.

```
/home/username/Mirrors/earth.com/tree/apples/filename2.html
/home/username/Mirrors/earth.com/grass/flower/leave/filename1.html
```

shoud later be files named like this:

```
earth.com/tree/apples/filename2.html
earth.com/earth/grass/flower/leave/filename1.html
```

ideally all located in one folder. Can this be done with a bash script and sed?

Why am I doing this: I am mirroring a huge Web site with httrack and httrack saves a file within its relative directory structure, I couldn't get httrack get to save a file as complete URL.

Comment: So you want to remove everything before `earth.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you haven't defined how many parent directories you want to be appended. Making that as runtime argument you can use following awk command:

```
echo /home/username/Mirrors/earth.com/tree/apples/filename2.html | 
awk  -F '/' -v D=3 '{for (i=D;i>=0;i--) {printf("%s", $(NF-i)); if (i>0) printf("/")}
 print "";}'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
earth.com/tree/apples/filename2.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with fixed fields, you can use a plethora of tools.

```
$ sed 's#/home/username/Mirrors##' file
/earth.com/tree/apples/filename2.html
/earth.com/grass/flower/leave/filename1.html

$ cut -c24- file
earth.com/tree/apples/filename2.html
earth.com/grass/flower/leave/filename1.html
```

Comment: Maybe I should add that I have a huge list and folder structure, all differently named, about 10.000 files in total.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
sed 's|^/home/username/Mirrors/||'
```

?

```
for f in /home/username/Mirrors/earth.com/*; do 
  mv $f `echo "$f" | sed 's|^/home/username/Mirrors/|/new/path/|'`;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it with `sed`, but `httrack` is capable, e.g.:

```
httrack http://earth.com/tree/apples/filename2.html -O /tmp/ -N100
```

According to the docs: `-N100` *Site-structure, without www.domain.xxx/*.

But more:

**Details: Option N**

- `N0` Site-structure (default)
- `N1` HTML in web/, images/other files in web/images/
- `N2` HTML in web/HTML, images/other in web/images
- `N3` HTML in web/,  images/other in web/
- `N4` HTML in web/, images/other in web/xxx, where xxx is the file extension
  (all gif will be placed onto web/gif, for example)
- `N5` Images/other in web/xxx and HTML in web/HTML
- `N99` All files in web/, with random names (gadget !)
- `N100` Site-structure, without www.domain.xxx/
- `N101` Identical to N1 exept that "web" is replaced by the site's name
- `N102` Identical to N2 exept that "web" is replaced by the site's name
- `N103` Identical to N3 exept that "web" is replaced by the site's name
- `N104` Identical to N4 exept that "web" is replaced by the site's name
- `N105` Identical to N5 exept that "web" is replaced by the site's name
- `N199` Identical to N99 exept that "web" is replaced by the site's name
- `N1001` Identical to N1 exept that there is no "web" directory
- `N1002` Identical to N2 exept that there is no "web" directory
- `N1003` Identical to N3 exept that there is no "web" directory (option set for g option)
- `N1004` Identical to N4 exept that there is no "web" directory
- `N1005` Identical to N5 exept that there is no "web" directory
- `N1099` Identical to N99 exept that there is no "web" directory

Comment: Well that will save a directory structure won't it? I need files to be named like this file: "test/test2/test3.html" <- this is not a path, it is the filename.